# Bit Shifting issue in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, xor, bit-shift

```
private static byte xtime(byte Tm)
{
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(Tm);
        int p1 = (p >> 7);
        int p2 = (p1 & 1);
        int p3=(p2 * 0x1b);
        int p4 = (p << 1);
        int p5 = p4 ^ p3;

        byte p6 = (Convert.ToByte(p5));

        return p6;
}
```

This function works fine when the output is lower than 255 but it crashes otherwise (**Overflow Exception**).

for e.g. if Tm is 163 the output should be 93 
(i got this value from executing the same code in C lang using unsigned char as datatype)

Can anyone suggest a way to make this function work?

Comment: Why are you using `int`s as intermediate values? Just make it `byte` everywhere.

Comment: Which line gets the `OverflowException`?

Comment: @Jacob `Convert.ToByte` no doubt.

Comment: Since byte p1 = (Tm >> 7); this gives an error of casting. Also XOR operator returns a int value.

Comment: @jacob p4 variable gives an error

Comment: I have tried unchecked block but same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look on [Convert.ToByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5949zd89(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, the only exception it produces is actually

`OverflowException` cause

> value is less than Byte.MinValue or greater than Byte.MaxValue.

and `p5` in your code becomes `349`.

To resolve this:

1) as mantioned in comments operate on `byte` type and do not convert it into the `int`

2) cast to `(byte)` where appropriate. cast *truncates* and does not generate exceptions.

so your final code may look like this (just coping without warring about semantics of the code):

```
    byte p1 = (byte)(Tm >> 7);
    byte p2 = (byte)(p1 & 1);
    byte p3=  (byte)(p2 * 0x1b);
    byte p4 = (byte)(Tm << 1);
    byte p5 = (byte)(p4 ^ p3);      
    byte p6 = p5;
```

and `p6 = 93` as required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `p4` is going to generate a value larger than what's allowed in a byte. If you *cast* to a `byte`, it will truncate the higher bits:

```
var p4 = (byte)(p << 1);
```